# docker ps | show image name instead of ID

Tags: docker, docker-command

When I run `docker ps`,it shows image IDs in the 2nd column:
[image]
But i want it to show image names:
[image]
what should I do ?

Comment: the name is in the right-most columns.

Comment: The names that you are seeing (angry_agnesi, loving_lamport..) are randomly generated names by docker cli. This happens when you don't supply a container name (--name <name>) in your docker run command or docker-compose.yml file. Also, these look like dangling docker images. Please run `docker system prune` first and then try deploying test containers, after which `docker ps` would give a correct output.

Comment: For starters, after `docker system prune` try running a hello-world container from docker-hub (`docker run hello-world`) and then check the output of `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to get **image** name : `docker ps -a --format 'table {{.Image}}'`

And this command for **container** name: `docker ps -a --format 'table {{.Names}}'`

Comment: This doesn't help in any way as it will still print the image IDs and not their names.

Comment: The original question asked is to show image name. Don't confuse container name with image name.

Comment: I don't confuse image and container name. I have the same issue as OP: `docker ps` shows the image ID and not the name, formatting using `{{.Image}}` just prints what's in the *IMAGE* column: for us, the ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because in the meantime the image name and tag was assigned to a different image.

*reproduce:*

```
docker pull ubuntu:22.04
docker tag ubuntu:22.04 myimage:mytag
docker run myimage:mytag
```

here if you do a `docker ps -a` you will see the container has `myimage:mytag` in the **IMAGE** column, however if you now tag a different image with this `myimage:mytag`:

```
docker pull debian:buster
docker tag debian:buster myimage:mytag
```

you will see the **IMAGE ID** in the **IMAGE** column of `docker ps -a` for the previous container because that tag doesn't belong to that image anymore.